# includeAll path="" not working in 3.5.3, using java -jar method

Tags: liquibase

We are having a major issue where the relative path is not working inside the `databaseChangeLogMaster.xml` file when using includeAll.

includeAll works only with absolute path. Example is below:

below does not work:

```
<includeAll path="sql/relativetest" />
```

below works fine:

```
<includeAll path="file:/oravl01/oracle/erd_folder/payment/capm/sql/function/" />
```

when we run the liquibase update using the `"java -jar"` method we get error for the relative path, below is the error, any help will be highly appreciated. Let me know if any more information is needed.

```
DEBUG 1/4/17 11:49 AM: liquibase: Opening jar:file:/oravl01/oracle/liquibase/liquibase.jar!/liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd as liquibase/parser/core/xml/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
....
INFO 1/4/17 11:49 AM: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sql/relativetest/'

SEVERE 1/4/17 11:49 AM: liquibase: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sql/relativetest/'
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sql/relativetest/'
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:27)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.getDatabaseChangeLog(Liquibase.java:229)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1130)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:188)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sql/relativetest/'
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:448)
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.handleChildNode(DatabaseChangeLog.java:352)
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.load(DatabaseChangeLog.java:282)
        at liquibase.parser.core.xml.AbstractChangeLogParser.parse(AbstractChangeLogParser.java:25)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'sql/relativetest/'
        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.includeAll(DatabaseChangeLog.java:441)
        ... 9 more
For more information, use the --logLevel flag
```

Comment: below does not work:
<includeAll path="sql/relativetest" />

below works fine:
<includeAll path="file:/oravl01/oracle/erd_folder/payment/capm/sql/function/" />

Comment: Run it again with the `--logLevel=debug`. Maybe it will give hints on why it cannot find your xml files. Liquibase might use class loader to find your resources. Are your xml files on your classpath?

Comment: Maybe this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/41678616/4864870. There are some technical details which could help liquibase developers to find the issue.

Comment: have you seen the relativeToChangelog attribute?